# Installation of software requires more free space on a Virtual Disk Image of Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, disk-usage

I'm trying to install a software called 'choregraphe'
and it requires at least 1091 mb of free space.

I'm running a virtual Ubuntu 14.04 LTS client on Virtual Box, with enough space. I even increased the disk space from 8Go to 12Go using the VBoxManage modifyhd.

But it didn't change the fact that it need more free space. It didn't increase the disk space in my vm.

How do I give more free space inside of my Virtual Machine?

Comment: Do you have partitions in your VM? what is the output of `df -h`?

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       5,2G  4,1G  794M  85% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1,3G  4,0K  1,3G   1% /dev
tmpfs           268M  948K  267M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            1,4G  152K  1,4G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user

Comment: I guess this is the important part:    /dev/sda1       5,2G  4,1G  794M  85% /

Comment: As you can see, `/dev/sda1` has only 794MB of free space. Expand your partition size, like @TheCompWiz suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you expand the partition to fill the volume?  More than likely, the disk is bigger, but the partition is still the same size.  Take a look at the `resize2fs` tool to resize the partition to fill the size of the disk.

Comment: You are right, the /dev/sda1  is still 5,2G. I'll try resize2fs. Thanks for the quick reply!